# AWS Lambda failing with run error "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/bridge.js'"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a Node.js 12.x AWS Lambda that is configured in [Serverless Framework](https://www.serverless.com/) to fire when a JSON file is dropped into a specific S3 bucket.

```
  Abcg:
    handler: Abcg.handle
    reservedConcurrency: 1
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
        Resource: ${cf:LocTransformer-${self:custom.stageEnv}.ABCFnArn}
    environment:
      GEO_TRANSFORMER_FN: ${self:custom.var.lambdaFn.LocTransformerABC}
      EVENT_SOURCE: ${self:custom.var.eventSourceEquipment}
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: ${self:custom.var.bucket}
          existing: true
          events:
            - s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: abcg/
            - suffix: .json
```

When a file is dropped, CloudWatch shows the Lambda invocation failing immediately with the following error:

```
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/bridge.js'",
    "code": "ENOENT",
    "errno": -2,
    "syscall": "open",
    "path": "/var/task/bridge.js",
    "stack": [
        "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/bridge.js'",
        "    at Object.openSync (fs.js:462:3)",
        "    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:364:35)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/Abcg.js:10201:60)",
        "    at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/Abcg.js:20:30)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/Abcg.js:59145:5)",
        "    at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/Abcg.js:20:30)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/Aabcg.js:59127:18)",
        "    at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/Aabcg.js:20:30)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/Aabcg.js:44894:15)",
        "    at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/Abcg.js:20:30)"
    ]
}
```

I believe it's failing even before entering my Lambda code because I have some early log statements and these aren't appearing in CloudWatch. And, the project doesn't use Webpack, so I assume this reference in the stack trace is coming from a dependency.

Has anyone seen this error before, in particular the reference to `/var/task/bridge.js`, which I can't see in my project?

Comment: See https://github.com/patriksimek/vm2/issues/440